# Installing Elementary Sdk unable to locate package

Tags: software-installation

I just recently wanted to install the elementary sdk with:

```
sudo apt install elementary-sdk
```

but it says

```
Unable to locate package elementary-sdk
```

I can't find another command to get the sdk because the developer page only states this package.
Has anyone got an idea to where I can find this package?

Comment: The command works fine for me, on loki. Have you edited your sources?